# how to push local repo to github from vscode wtithout creating repo on github?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

is it possible to push locally created folder to github without creating corresponding repo on github first?

my steps:

1. create 2 py files in vscode
2. git init
3. git add . then git commit then git push

It still asks me to give link to repo on github.
How can i specify the repo name from VSCode and then push it, so it will create it on github automatically?

Comment: The short answer is "no": VonC's longer answer gives you a way to create the repo on GitHub *from the command line*, but you're still *creating the repo on GitHub first*. This is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- install the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/manual/installation)
- install the VSCode extension [GitHub CLI UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NickCernis.github-cli-ui) (optional, because it only supports pull requests commands for now)

From there, you can use, from VSCode, the [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) command.

Open a terminal at the root folder of your repository, and type:

```
echo "my_GitHub_token" | gh auth login --with-token
gh repo create myNewRepo --source=.
```

- Make sure to create first a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), with [`repo` and `admin:org` scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps), and an expiration date set to 'none', or to any expiration date you want
- Replace 'myNewRepo' with the name of the repository you want to create.

The point is: with the [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) '`gh`', you can do most GitHub-related operation directly from your workstation.